# Как при нажатии на кнопку вывести записи определенной рубрики?

Tags: php, wordpress

На странице есть записи с одной общей рубрикой (ограды) При нажатии на кнопку мне надо вывести записи с новой рубрики (рубрика уже создана) и только их (например: вертикальные памятники и их что бы выбило) 
Есть код выведения записей:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : 
query_posts('cat=9');   
while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
?>
<div class="new-items-numb bottom">
<div class="new-item-picture">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
</div>
<span class="item-model"><?php echo the_title(); ?>     
</span>                                                                                    
<input class="item-button" type="button" value="Заказать">
</div>
<?php
endwhile;  
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Проблема не ясна - страница рубрики всё и выведет. А этот - древний и опасный. Его нельзя уже использовать.

Comment: @SeVlad Проблема в том, можно ли при нажатии на кнопку на этой же странице, на которой выводится одни записи с определенной рубрикой, вывести другие записи другой рубрике, и как это написать на кнопке. Спасибо